# Lexmark 705 Pro install

Tags: 11.04

I am trying to install Lexmark 705pro printer that is wireless. When I go to install the drivers is ask's for admin password. I enter the password that works for installing software and everything else but it says incorrect password. I have no other password on the system. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure that caps lock is not on seeing that they are case sensitive! Try not to type it to fast you might be tying the password wrong by getting in a hurry.

Answer (score 1):

Lexmark goofed.  You need to run this as root.

1. Copy the file to your Desktop and open a terminal.
2. Type `cd Desktop` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the Desktop folder.
3. Type `sudo ./lexm` <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> and this should finish the file name for you.  Hit  and then enter your password when prompted.

If this doesn't work, then you probably aren't in the same directory as the file, or you haven't extracted it yet (if you downloaded it as a tarball).